# how to assign std::initializer_list to a vector

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdinitializerlist

This is a constructor which requires an `std::initializer_list` and I want to assign it to a vector. Do I need to use a `for`-loop to assign each item in the `std::initializer_list` to the vector one by one?

```cpp
Motor_Group::Motor_Group(std::initializer_list<pros::Motor> port_set)
{
  this->motor_vector = port_set;
}
```

Comment: Have you just *tried* using plain assignment, like in the shown code?

Comment: yes i had, it showed me a junk pile of error message, and when i commented it works

Comment: According to documentation, `std::vector` has an assignment operator which accepts an initializer list: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D

Comment: Then perhaps you should ask about the errors you get, considering that it should work. Direct questions about errors will always be quicker to ask and get answers for, than sneaking around the actual issues and problems with indirect questions like this.

Comment: I think a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help a lot here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```cpp
this->motor_vector = std::vector{port_set};
```

or better, use the initialization list:

```cpp
Motor_Group::Motor_Group(std::initializer_list<pros::Motor> port_set)
    : motor_vector{port_set} {}
```

Answer (score 5):

> Do i need to use a for loop [...]?

No. In order to initialize `Motor_Group::motor_vector` of type `std::vector<pros::Motor>`, you should use the member initializer list of the constructor `Motor::Group`:

```
Motor_Group::Motor_Group(std::initializer_list<pros::Motor> port_set) :
    motor_vector{port_set}
{}
```

Initialization should be preferred over assignment in constructor bodies, as it results in an unnecessary invocation of the data member's default constructor first. This isn't necessarily a measurable performance penalty (it could be, in rare cases, though), but a control flow that requires more thoughts than plain initialization.